# Same texture displayed. Binding issue?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, opengl-es, textures

Today a wild bug that I had several times before appeared again...!

And I don't know how to fix it. I hope you know a trick to solve the problem or an official way to get it work. Some of tutorials don't seem to work the correct way they promise.

I have some quads, displayed as pictures on my Surfaceview. I also have two textures. One for the tiles and the walls and one for the objects so far.

I draw tiles and objects in my own order of isometric system. (because of preventing overlapping images)
On my smartphone, it works very well. The tiles use the texture of tiles and the objects use the texture of objects.

[image: The cube is just for testing fusion of 2D and 3D]
As you can see. The room itself is drawn with the first texture. The ovens are drawn with the second. (I use Xperia Mini Pro)

A friend of mine uses Galaxy S. And now, something weird is happening. All quads are using the same texture. There's no obvious solution I found how to fix the bug.
Here the image taken with a camera:
[image]
In the second texture there are also red tiles, so don't wonder about the color. Fact is, that all tiles suddenly use the first texture. You cannot see any parts drawn with the second one.

Here are some of my drawing functions:

Function for drawing pictures:

```
public void render(float posX, float posY) {
    // ======== Pass Masking Color ========
    if (this.masked) {
        GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderCache.activeShader.masked, 1);
        GLES20.glUniform3i(ShaderCache.activeShader.maskColor, this.maskColor.r, this.maskColor.g, this.maskColor.b);
    } else {
        GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderCache.activeShader.masked, 0);
    }
    // ======== Passing Vertex And UV Attributes ========
    if (ImageCache.lastUsedImageBuffer != this.buffer) {
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderCache.activeShader.attributeVertex, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderCache.activeShader.attributeUV, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
        ImageCache.lastUsedImageBuffer = this.buffer;
    }
    // ======== Set Sampler Texture2D ========
    if (TextureCache.lastTextureUnit != this.imagetexture.unit) {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.imagetexture.unit);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderCache.activeShader.texture, this.imagetexture.unit);
        TextureCache.lastTextureUnit = this.imagetexture.unit;
    }
    // ======== Passing Image Position ========
    GLES20.glUniform2f(ShaderCache.activeShader.position, posX, posY);
    // ======== Draw Arrays With Image Vertices ========
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this.vertices);
}
```

And here the function just for generating textureunits:

```
int[] textureID = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureID, 0);
this.unit = textureID[0];
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + this.unit);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.unit);
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.imagetexture.unit);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(ShaderCache.activeShader.texture, this.imagetexture.unit);
```

I believe this is wrong. The sampler2d uniform value that you pass to glsl should be the number of the **sampler**, not the id of the texture. If you bind texture id 3 to sampler 0 (glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)), then you pass 0 to the uniform sampler2d, not 3. If you bind a texture to GL_TEXTURE1, then the sampler2d value becomes 1, etc.

Comment: Never read this in a tutorial. But I believe you! Sounds kind of logical. I'll try it out and make a report ;)